# git での pushRemote と remote

Tags: git

リポジトリの、 git の config のファイルを見ていました。 branch に対する設定として、 `branch.BRANCHNAME.pushRemote` と `branch.BRANCHNAME.remote` を、別々に設定できるようになっていることに気付きました。

#### 質問

- git の branch の設定として、 pushRemote と remote の違いは何ですか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-config`によると
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

> ```
>    branch.<name>.remote
>        When on branch <name>, it tells git fetch and git push which remote
>        to fetch from/push to. The remote to push to may be overridden with
>        remote.pushDefault (for all branches). The remote to push to, for
>        the current branch, may be further overridden by
>        branch.<name>.pushRemote. If no remote is configured, or if you are
>        not on any branch, it defaults to origin for fetching and
>        remote.pushDefault for pushing. Additionally, .  (a period) is the
>        current local repository (a dot-repository), see
>        branch.<name>.merge's final note below.
>
>    branch.<name>.pushRemote
>        When on branch <name>, it overrides branch.<name>.remote for
>        pushing. It also overrides remote.pushDefault for pushing from
>        branch <name>. When you pull from one place (e.g. your upstream)
>        and push to another place (e.g. your own publishing repository),
>        you would want to set remote.pushDefault to specify the remote to
>        push to for all branches, and use this option to override it for a
>        specific branch.
> ```

`branch.<name>.remote`はfetchとpushする際のリモートを指定(通常はこちらだけでOK)、
`branch.<name>.pushRemote`の方は`.remote`の値を上書きしてpushするリモート先を指定、の様です。

フォークしたリポジトリを追いかけていて、fetchはフォーク元(`branch.master.remote=upstream`)から取得するけど、push先はフォークした自分のリポジトリ(`branch.master.pushRemote=origin`)、みたいな使い方でしょうか。

---

**追記**
このオプションを知ってからフォークしたリポジトリでは`branch.master.pushRemote=origin`を毎回個別に指定していましたが、フォークした場合の`push`先は大抵自分のリポジトリ(`origin`)なので、グローバル設定として`remote.pushDefault=origin`を指定した方が楽なのかもしれないと思いました。
(フォーク元を`upstream`、フォーク先を`origin`で管理する場合)